# Python `invoke` not printing with multiline commands on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyinvoke

When using the [invoke](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/) library from Windows, it seems like no output is printed to the terminal if the command spans multiple lines. Here's an example to reproduce; put this in `tasks.py`.

```py
import invoke

@invoke.task
def test_oneline(ctx):
    ctx.run("pip install nonexistant-package1234")

@invoke.task
def test_multiline(ctx):
    ctx.run(
    """
    pip install nonexistant-package1234
    """
    )
```

Then, from the command prompt in the same directory as `tasks.py`, I get the following:

```
>invoke test-oneline
Collecting nonexistant-package1234
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nonexistant-package1234 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for nonexistant-package1234
>
```

```
>invoke test-multiline

>
```

Doing the same thing on Linux (well, at least Windows Subsystem for Linux) works as expected:

```sh
$ invoke test-multiline
Collecting nonexistant-package1234
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nonexistant-package1234 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for nonexistant-package1234
$
```

Is there a way to get the output printed in Windows for multi-line commands?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the hack that I'm using for now in case others need to circumvent this in the short run. I'll post back if I encounter issues with it; it's only minimally tested so far. Basically, if you're on Windows, I just write the command into a `.bat` file, then I run the `.bat` file (as a single-line command).

```py
import invoke
import platform
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory


def _fixed_run(ctx, cmd: str, *args, **kwargs):
    if platform.system() != "Windows":
        return ctx._old_run(cmd, *args, **kwargs)

    with TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
        tmp_file = Path(tmp_dir) / "tmp.bat"
        tmp_file.write_text("@echo off\r\n" + cmd)
        return ctx._old_run(str(tmp_file), *args, **kwargs)

invoke.Context._old_run = invoke.Context.run
invoke.Context.run = _fixed_run
```

To use this easily, save it into a file (e.g. `fix_invoke.py` and then just do `import fix_invoke` whenever you need this fix).

I'd be glad to hear of a real solution, though, if anybody has one!